# Are there any blog focusing on Google App Engine topics?

Tags: google-app-engine

Book are good for teaching and telling us how to use a kind of technology but the update frequency is too slow, it takes time to write and publish a book!

So, are there any blogs that focus on Google App Engine's topics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the blogs I am following in my feed reader.

[Datanucleus GAE plugin](http://datanucleus.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)

[Software developer inside GAE](http://ikaisays.com/feed/)

[Another interesting blog](http://blog.notdot.net/feeds/atom.xml)

Comment: > "Software developer inside GAE"
This is Ikai Lan blog, he works for App Engine Developer Relations
, > "Another interesting blog"
This is Nick Johnson blog, he also works for App Engine Developer Relations

Comment: "I Kai Lan" Blog is a good blog. Met the guy last year and he is a very knowledgeable yet a nice guy.

Comment: I know, he's my friend :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is [The official blog for GAE.](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/)